# Undo 401k to IRA rollover?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira, rollover

After I left my employer I rolled my 401k over to a traditional and Roth IRA (Roth for after tax contributions, traditional for everything else), but am having second thoughts. Is there any way to "undo" the rollover(s)?

Comment: Can you add a few lines about why you regret the rollover decision?

Comment: There are a couple of reasons I regret it. First, there are some things I don't like about the IRA custodian. Most are personal preferences, not supporting Quicken download, and I find their web site difficult to use, etc., and a couple of the mutual funds I had in my 401(k) were private to the 401(k) provider so I can't get them in the IRAs. Of course as Ben notes, that's all fixable by simply switching IRA custodians, which is what I'll end up doing. The second reason is that after (of course) I did the rollover, I got a great offer from one of my current brokerages to roll over a 401(k).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably not.  You've left your employer, so you aren't eligible to contribute to the 401(k) anymore.  After you've left, they are required to keep your account open as long as you like, but after you've rolled it over to something else and closed your account, they are not going to let you open your 401(k) account up again.

However, you need to ask yourself: Why do you want to go back to your 401(k) from your IRA?  401(k) accounts are generally very restrictive as to what you can invest in; they usually give you a small list of investing options.  IRAs, on the other hand, are generally open to any investment you like, limited only by your imagination.  If you aren't happy with your current IRA custodian, roll it over into a new one.  I'm sure you'll be able to find an IRA with the same investment that you are looking for from your 401(k).

Comment: Thanks. I figured it wasn't possible but thought there might be some loophole I don't know about. I added a comment on why I'd like to go back to my 401(k). It would just be temporary, I'd still end up rolling it to IRAs.

Answer (score 6):

It is unlikely that you can undo the rollover and put money back into the 401(k) plan sponsored by your *ex*-employer, and even more so if your departure was acrimonious. You could, of course, always *ask* your
ex-employer for permission to put the money back, but I suspect that a
rollover from an IRA into a 401(k) is not permitted
*unless* you *resume* employment with your ex-employer.

The real question is *what* is it in your
ex-employer's 401(k) plan that makes you want to go back there? As a general rule, 401(k) plans have much larger expenses, and
a lousy selection of funds in which to invest.

Comment: Thanks. I marked your comment as useful, although that won't show up until I get more reputation points.